# How to fix lmer error: "Error in as(value, fieldClass, strict=FALSE) :"?

Tags: r, lme4

I'm getting a strange error when I run an lmer function in r.

I've tried changing the variable types (all of them are numeric or factor) and removing the NA before analysis, but nothing seems to work.

```
model_1 <- lmer(Q14 ~ gender * time  + (1|OMID), data=data)
summary(model_1)
```

Specifically, my error message reads:

```
Error in as(value, fieldClass, strict = FALSE) : 
  internal problem in as(): “labelled” is(object, "numeric") is TRUE, but the metadata asserts that the 'is' relation is FALSE
```

Not sure why this is happening, but I can't seem to find any answers for it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try running `lapply(data, class)` and see what the actual classes of the variables in the data frame are.

Answer (score 0):

I think lmer has a problem with 'labelled' data. If you un-label the predictors it should work fine.

Comment: This seems more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error: the code for the lme-formula worked perfectly fine and one day I encountered that error. The solution in my case was simply to restart the R session, reload the data - in my case from SPSS via library("haven")::read.sps and after that load library("lme4") and execute the lme-formula.
So, if the formula worked before without any error, maybe just clean the project environment and re-run the most crucial code without any additional packages loaded. Maybe it's just some "cross-contamination" between packages or an unwanted effect of any package on the dataframe.

Comment: I think you should consider adding more [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) to your answer. I think that would make it easier to read and understand.